# invite friends to created event using Graph API javascript

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api

on my website users can already create facebook-events, but I can't figure out how to invite a list of selected user' friends to the newly created event by using the Graph API in javascript.

I already found lots of code examples using PHP but none using Javascript. 
This is from the fb developer site:

> "You can invite multiple users by issuing an HTTP POST to
>   /EVENT_ID/invited?users=USER_ID1,USER_ID2,USER_ID3."

but what code do I have to use to do so? My last try was:

```
FB.api('/EVENT_ID/invited?users=USER1_ID,USER2_ID','post', function(response) {
    alert(response);
}
```

I've been searching for days now, please help me :)

Answer (score 0):

I just discovered that you'll get a 200 error if you try and add the access tokens UID to the invitees list (yourself basically)... Took this into the graph explorer and kept trying my command, removing one UID at a time, and once I locked onto the offending UID the rest went through fine.

Try fooling around in the Graph Explorer - https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=731980402

Comment: Hi, Thank you very much for your reply! But I don't understand it quite well, what is your solution exactly?

Comment: The code from your last try was right.. at least that much worked for me.  You have to have calendar_edit access token.  I just stumbled into your question while looking for the answer to min (a similar problem, I was using the same code you were bug getting an error response 200).

Comment: I know this is a very old post but does anyone know how to invite a friend in todays Graph API 2.7 ? _(#12) invited field is deprecated for versions v2.4 and higher_

Comment: You can't do it anymore.  Helpfully, Facebook removed this entire functionality in 2014.  Yeah... thanks for that....